# Does a nondegenerate alternating map determines the exponent of the group?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, i.e., $G$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Consider the second component of the exterior algebra of $G$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, $\wedge^2 G=G\wedge G$. Suppose that $a:G\wedge G\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is a nonzero, *nondegenerate* alternating form.

Does it follow that the exponent of the group $G$ and exponent of the *image* of $a$ is same?

Note that since $a$ is a nondegenerate form, the group $G$ is not cyclic.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What are your thoughts regarding the question and how you might address it?  Have you tried to answer this?

Comment: I was thinking to use structure theorem for finite abelian groups. But do not know how to proceed. Also if there is a 'symplectic basis' as in vector space case then it might follow easily.